# Creating a sketch to place random images at mouse positions in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I am currently working on a sketch for p5.js that places two random images at a location the user clicks on in the canvas. The idea is to create a "paper doll" of a character with a randomized head and a randomized body at any location where the user chooses to click. The random images in question are the image for the head and the image for the body. I decided to name the images with numbers so that I could use string interpolation to randomize the images with the numbers in the name of the images.

I have already managed to successfully display the paper doll without randomization of the images, but I now can't seem to successfully randomize the two different images upon mouse click. How can I randomize the images displayed using this type of string interpolation technique?

```html
let body = [];
let head = [];
let characters = [];

function preload() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    body[i] = loadImage('Body_' + i + '.png')
     console.log(print(body[i]));
  }
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    head[i] = loadImage('Head_' + i + '.png')
     console.log(print(head[i]));
  }
 
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
}

function mousePressed() {
  let R = random(0, 1);
  let c = new pcCharacter(R, mouseX - 150, mouseY - 300)
  characters.push(c);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    characters[i].characterDraw();
  }
}
// a class for the paperdoll
class pcCharacter {
  constructor(r, x, y) {
    this.r = r;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  characterDraw() {

    image(body[this.r], this.x, this.y + 130)
    image(head[this.r], this.x + 60, this.y)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make two new variables (say a and b)

assign them random values between 0 and 3

floor the variables

load only the body[a] and face[b]

make the doll using only these images.